# android.widget.EditText cast issue on tablet device

Tags: android

Android 4.2.2 / Android Studio

It works fine on cell phone devices.
***only on tablet devices*** I got  :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to br.com.formshelper.EditTextHelper
```

ON CREATE MAIN ACTIVITY - EXTENDS ACTIVITY

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    userHelper = new UserFormsHelperImpl(this);  /*cast exception here*/
```

USERFORMSHELPER

```
public class UserFormsHelperImpl {

private EditTextHelper userEMail;
private EditTextHelper userPassword;

public UserFormsHelperImpl(MainActivity activity) {
    this.userEMail = (EditTextHelper) activity.findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    this.userPassword = (EditTextHelper) activity.findViewById(R.id.editTextSenha);
```

EDITTEXTHELPER CLASS

```
public class EditTextHelper extends EditText {

private KeyImeChange keyImeChangeListener;

public EditTextHelper(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public void setKeyImeChangeListener(KeyImeChange listener){
    keyImeChangeListener = listener;
}

public interface KeyImeChange {
    public void onKeyIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyPreIme (int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    if(keyImeChangeListener != null){
        keyImeChangeListener.onKeyIme(keyCode, event);
    }
    return false;
}
```

ACTIVITY

```
        userHelper.getUserEMail().setKeyImeChangeListener(new EditTextHelper.KeyImeChange() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                clearEditTextsFocus();
                setContentViewResized(false, false, true, true);
            }
        }
    });
```

XML

```
<br.com.formshelper.EditTextHelper
                android:layout_width="294dp"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
```

I think there is some thing related to pysical back button that does not exist on tablets and does exists on the cells phones. 
But I dont know how to handle this.....

Comment: it seems like your import line in the EditTextHelper class is not the right one. Check if it is `import android.widget.EditText;`
Or in `USERFORMSHELPER` you have a not needed import for EditTextHelper as an external class, check there if it is the correct import, too

Comment: the import in EditTextHelper is correct : android.widget.EditText;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception says, that EditText was found and you tried cast it to your custom view - so EditText was created instead of your custom view.

Check alternative of your layout xml files for bigger screens - you can find them in folder res/layout-sw720 or res/layout-sw600. You need to change views with ids editTextEmail and editTextSenha to your custom view class.

Comment: You are totally right.I was so focused on this issue that I forgot to change my OLD alternative xml file . Fixed the issue.   THANKS :)